# OData Navigation-Routing for a Generic-Controller with ODataQueryOptions-support

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, odata

I have one generic-controller (similar to this: [.Net Core Override Controller Route for Generic Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291370/net-core-override-controller-route-for-generic-controller)) which registers generic implementations for all dynamic types, I have.

This works very well. But while trying to implement the support navigation-routing with additional filter-values I have some issues. This example:

http://localhost/odata/EntityA(4711)/SubEntity?$filter=category eq 'ABC'

works theoretically, but I need to extract the ODataQueryOptions.

So this is what I have so far:

**ExternalControllerFeatureProvider**

```
public class ExternalControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        foreach (var candidate in _entityCompiler.GetTypes())
        {
            feature.Controllers.Add(
                typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(candidate).GetTypeInfo()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**GenericController**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[GenericControllerNameConvention]
[EnableQuery]
public class GenericController<T> : ODataController
{
    public async Task<IQueryable<T>> Get([FromServices] ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions)
    {
        var parameters = ExtractQueryParameter(odataQueryOptions);

        return await InternalGet(parameters);
    }

    public async Task<IQueryable<T>> Get([FromServices] ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions, [FromODataUri] object key)
    {
        var parameters = ExtractQueryParameter(odataQueryOptions);
        AppendKeyAttributeFilter(parameters, key);

        return await InternalGet(parameters);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNavigation(Guid key, string propertyName)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        AppendKeyAttributeFilter(parameters, key);
        AppendExpandFilter(parameters, propertyName);

        var rootObject = await InternalGet(parameters);

        if (rootObject.Any())
        {
            var info = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

            object value = info.GetValue(rootObject.FirstOrDefault());

            return Ok(value);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Similar to this (http://odata.github.io/WebApi/03-04-custom-routing-convention/) I created a **NavigationRoutingConvention**, which extracts the navigation-property and calls the **GetNavigation**-method from the **GenericController** with the correct **propertyName**.

The problem is that this GenericController-method can not return **IQueryable** nor **IEnumerable**, but only some untyped types like **IActionResult**.

In order to manually filter my datasource in the backend I need the **ODataQueryOptions**, like in the both Get-methods. The problem is that it seems that the underleying framework needs to know the correct returned type.

If I add **[FromServices] ODataQueryOptions** to the method-head I get following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create an EDM model as the
>   action 'GetNavigation' on controller 'EntityA' has a return type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' that does not
>   implement IEnumerable.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataQueryParameterBindingAttribute.ODataQueryParameterBinding.GetEntityClrTypeFromActionReturnType(ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataQueryParameterBindingAttribute.ODataQueryParameterBinding.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext
>   actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider,
>   ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution. I have abstained from the idea of my own routing convention and added a further Generic-Controller especially for sub-navigation properties. Below the abstract not working code, cleaned by some private parts... :-)

**GenericSubNavigationController**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[GenericControllerNameConvention]
[EnableQuery]
public class GenericSubNavigationController<TBaseType, TSubType, TSubTypeDeclared> : GenericControllerBase<TBaseType>
{
    public GenericSubNavigationController(ISubTypeEnricher subTypeEnricher) : base(subTypeEnricher)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IQueryable<TSubTypeDeclared>> GetNavigation([FromServices] ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions, Guid key)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(TBaseType).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(TSubType));

        string propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        AppendKeyAttributeFilter(parameters, key);
        AppendExpandFilter(parameters, propertyName);

        var subParameters = new Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(propertyName, ExtractQueryParameter(odataQueryOptions));

        var rootObject = await InternalGet<TBaseType>(parameters, subParameters);

        if (rootObject.Any())
        {
            var info = typeof(TBaseType).GetProperty(propertyName);

            object value = info.GetValue(rootObject.FirstOrDefault());

            return new EnumerableQuery<TSubTypeDeclared>((IEnumerable<TSubTypeDeclared>) value);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In order to work, you have to instantiate this controller in the **ExternalControllerFeatureProvider**, which was already mentioned in my initial question

**ExternalControllerFeatureProvider**

```
public class ExternalControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    private readonly IExternalCompiler _entityCompiler;

    public ExternalControllerFeatureProvider(IExternalCompiler entityCompiler)
    {
        _entityCompiler = entityCompiler;
    }

    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        var types = _entityCompiler.GetTypes().ToList();
        foreach (var candidate in types)
        {
            feature.Controllers.Add(
                typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(candidate).GetTypeInfo()
            );

            foreach (var propertyInfo in candidate.GetProperties())
            {
                Type targetType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Any()
                    ? propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First()
                    : propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                if (types.Contains(targetType))
                {
                    var typeInfo = typeof(GenericSubNavigationController<,,>).MakeGenericType(candidate, propertyInfo.PropertyType, targetType).GetTypeInfo();
                    feature.Controllers.Add(typeInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally we have to change the used attribute **GenericControllerNameConvention** to change the action-name of the methods to reflact the default OData requirements

**GenericControllerNameConvention**

```
public class GenericControllerNameConvention : Attribute, IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        if (!controller.ControllerType.IsGenericType || (controller.ControllerType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() !=
            typeof(GenericController<>) && controller.ControllerType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() !=
            typeof(GenericSubNavigationController<,,>)))
        {
            // Not a GenericController, ignore.
            return;
        }

        var entityType = controller.ControllerType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        controller.ControllerName = $"{entityType.Name}";

        if (controller.ControllerType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
            typeof(GenericSubNavigationController<,,>))
        {
            foreach (var controllerAction in controller.Actions)
            {
                if (controllerAction.ActionName == "GetNavigation")
                {
                    var subType = controller.ControllerType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == subType);

                    controllerAction.ActionName = $"Get{propertyInfo.Name}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```