# In an ASP.NET core action method, how do I bind form data to one type or another based on the value of a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Say I have an action method like this, and I want to use the default model binder to bind to a different type based on the value of the variable "state":

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyActionMethod()
    {
        var dataContainer = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session.GetDataContainer();
        var state = dataContainer.USState;

        if (state == "KS")
        {
            ViewModelTypeA viewModel = (bind form data to ViewModelTypeA)

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await viewModel.SaveViewModelAsync(dataContainer);
                return RedirectToAction("AnotherActionMethod", "AnotherController");
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModelTypeB viewModel = (bind form data to ViewModelTypeB)

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await viewModel.SaveViewModelAsync(dataContainer);
                return RedirectToAction("AnotherActionMethod", "AnotherController");
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

I have been searching around, but most of the information I've found on model binding is how to do custom binding, which is not really what I'm after. I just want to use the default model binder so I get all the default functionality without having to manually handle data validation or whatever else is done automatically by the default model binder. I don't need any custom functionality other than choosing the type to bind to based on the value of the state variable.

ChatGPT recommended I try this when I asked it how to bind to different model types in the same action based on the value of a variable:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] object data)
{
    if (modelType == "A")
    {
        var modelA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelA>(data.ToString());
        // use modelA here
    }
    else if (modelType == "B")
    {
        var modelB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelB>(data.ToString());
        // use modelB here
    }
    else
    {
        // handle unknown model type
    }

    // return response
}
```

"[FromBody]" failed (got HTTP 415 error) so I removed it. Then it got to deserialization, but that failed because obviously data.ToString() is not the form data (just the fully qualified type name) and it's not JSON either. Then I realized I probably need to use the model binder, but I don't really want to use a custom model binder and have to do manual work.

Comment: MVC Binding occurs before the action is called. Binding different models to the same action based on some hidden state sounds like a terrible design choice. The caller should know which action they are calling, with which model. In other words, you should create one action per model, and define separate endpoints to route requests to them specifically.

Comment: Note that you can implement `IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>` to register multiple instances of the same generic controller with different type parameters. eg https://medium.com/@ajays871/generic-rest-controller-and-generic-entity-framework-implementation-in-asp-net-core-application-a91b18507b55 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291370/net-core-override-controller-route-for-generic-controller